# How can I avoid hard-coding sensitive values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, security

I'm working on putting AngularJS on top of an existing Rails API. Part of the authentication process involves passing a "secret key".

I need to pass the secret key in order to authenticate, but I can't think of any way to pass the secret key without actually including it somewhere in the JavaScript.

I imagine this is either a common challenge or we're doing some things way wrong. How can I avoid hard-coding this key?

Comment: If it is on the clientside, there is no secure way to do it.

Comment: What is the front-end code authenticating with that it needs a secret key? Are there multiple APIs, and it needs to authenticate with a second?

Comment: If a secret key is required, the API call should usually be done from the server rather than the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually what I have seen is that the client requests a user-specific token from the API and then sends it back over HTTPS on a per request basis.

If the secret key is shared across all clients then you have to do more work. One way to handle this would be to create a proxy that generates and accepts user-specific tokens on the frontend and uses the shared key on the backend. The JS would talk to the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way to do this without the user being able to figure it out. Even if you don't include it in the js (which is almost impossible in itself), anyone can just use their browser devtools to inspect the network requests and see the key that way.